# I want to unit test this login method

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, nunit, moq

I want to unit test this method

> SignInViewModel.cs

```
public ICommand LoginCommand { get; }
private async Task LogIn()
{
    var user = _userService.LoginUser(EmailEntry);

    if (user == null)
    {
        await _pageService.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Invalid Credentials", "Ok");
        return;
    }

    if (user.Password != PasswordEntry)
    {
        await _pageService.DisplayAlert("Alert", "Invalid Credentials", "Ok");
        return;
    }

    PasswordEntry = "";
    await _pageService.PushAsync(new HomePage(user));
}
```

I am trying to unit test this, but nothing work, can anyone please give me examples ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are.

```
[TestFixture]
public class Fixture
{
    private Mock<IUserService> _userService;
    private Mock<IPageService> _pageService;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _userService = new Mock<IUserService>();
        _pageService = new Mock<IPageService>();
    }

    [Test]
    public void LoginUserShouldBeCalled()
    {
        // Given
        var vm = CreateInstance();
        vm.EmailEntry = "email?";

        // When
        vm.LoginCommand.Execute(null);

        // Then
        _userService.Verify(x => x.LoginUser("email?"), Times.Once);
        _userService.VerifyNoOtherCalls();
    }

    [Test]
    public void DisplayAlertShouldBeCalledForNotFoundUser()
    {
        // Given
        var vm = CreateInstance();
        vm.EmailEntry = "not@found.user";
        _userService.Setup(x => x.LoginUser("not@found.user")).Returns((User)null).Verifiable();

        // When
        vm.LoginCommand.Execute(null);

        // Then
        _userService.Verify();
        _pageService.Verify(x => x.DisplayAlert(It.IsAny<string>(), "Invalid Credentials", It.IsAny<string>()));
        _pageService.VerifyNoOtherCalls();
    }

    [Test]
    public void DisplayAlertShouldBeCalledForInvalidPassword()
    {
        // Given
        var vm = CreateInstance();
        vm.EmailEntry    = "test@email.ru";
        vm.PasswordEntry = "password";
        _userService.Setup(x => x.LoginUser(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(new User(vm.EmailEntry, "ppppp")).Verifiable();

        // When
        vm.LoginCommand.Execute(null);

        // Then
        _userService.Verify();
        _pageService.Verify(x => x.DisplayAlert(It.IsAny<string>(), "Invalid Credentials", It.IsAny<string>()));
        _pageService.VerifyNoOtherCalls();
    }

    [Test]
    public void DisplayAlertShouldBeCalledForInvalidPassword2()
    {
        // Given
        var vm = CreateInstance();
        vm.EmailEntry    = "test@email.ru";
        vm.PasswordEntry = "password";
        User user = new User(vm.EmailEntry, vm.PasswordEntry);
        _userService.Setup(x => x.LoginUser(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(user).Verifiable();

        // When
        vm.LoginCommand.Execute(null);

        // Then
        _userService.Verify();
        _pageService.Verify(x => x.PushAsync(It.Is<HomePage>(x => x.User == user)));
        _pageService.VerifyNoOtherCalls();
        vm.PasswordEntry.Should().BeEmpty();
    }

    private SignInViewModel CreateInstance()
    {
        return new SignInViewModel(_userService.Object, _pageService.Object);
    }
}
```

You can play with it here https://github.com/zanybaka/StackOverflow.com/tree/master/Questions/63741243

Comment: Thank You @ZanyBaka for you Answer, but last test case is showing error Moq.MockException : 
Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: p => p.PushAsync(It.IsAny<HomePage>())

Comment: I've rechecked - all the tests are green in my test solution. Could you share your test? You can also debug your own code to be find out why the method is not called.